# concatenate SVG along with html

Tags: html, reactjs, svg, html-react-parser

I have an SVG, i want to add that svg in front of some html data.

```
import * as Parser from 'html-react-parser';

var loadingLogo = require('./img/loading.svg');
var htmlData = 'hello <b>World</b>'


let imgTag = Parser(loadingLogo);
imgTag.props.height = "20";
imgTag.props.width = "100";

var output = imgTag + htmlData
```

> This is what i get

[object Object]hello **World**

how to make it work so that i have an svg image along with the html

Answer (score 0):

okay since i couldnt figure it out, i did this, thought i am sure there is a better way

```
var outPut = Parser('{*theentiresvgcode*}' + htmlData);
```